# Importing items from QuickBooks using QuickBooks PHP Dev Kit/ QuickBooks Web Connector

Tags: php, mysql, sql, import, quickbooks

I am having trouble getting QuickBooks PHP Dev Kit to import my items. QuickBooks Web Connector log shows

> Error message: Response is not well-formed XML.

The only real leads I have right now are:

- Invalid request
- Incorrect parsing

**Relevant snippet from the Web Connector log file:**

```
20161227.23:47:12 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : hresult=""
20161227.23:47:12 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : message=""
20161227.23:47:12 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : QBWC1042: ReceiveResponseXML failed
Error message: Response is not well-formed XML.
More info:
StackTrace =    at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at QBWebConnector.localhost.WCWebServiceDoc.receiveResponseXML(String ticket, String response, String hresult, String message)
   at QBWebConnector.localhost.WCWebService.receiveResponseXML(String ticket, String response, String hresult, String message)
   at QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.receiveResponseXML(String wcTicket, String response, String hresult, String message)
   at QBWebConnector.WebService.do_receiveResponseXML(String wcTicket, String response, String hresult, String message, Boolean& success, Boolean& timeout)
Source = System.Web.Services
20161227.23:47:12 UTC   : QBWebConnector.CompanyFileLock.Send_CompanyQueryRqXML() : XML dump follows: -
```

**inventory_manager.php** (based on example_web_connector_import.php)

```
<?php
// I always program in E_STRICT error mode... 
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
// We need to make sure the correct timezone is set, or some PHP installations will complain
if (function_exists('date_default_timezone_set'))
{
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
}
// If you're having trouble with performance or memory usage, you can tell the 
//  framework to only include certain chunks of itself:
// require_once 'QuickBooks/Frameworks.php';
// define('QUICKBOOKS_FRAMEWORKS', QUICKBOOKS_FRAMEWORK_WEBCONNECTOR);
// Require the framework
require_once '../../QuickBooks.php';
// User & pass for QWC
$user = 'removed';
$pass = 'removed';
// Globals
define('QB_QUICKBOOKS_CONFIG_LAST', 'last');
define('QB_QUICKBOOKS_CONFIG_CURR', 'curr');
define('QB_QUICKBOOKS_MAILTO', 'removed');
define('QB_QUICKBOOKS_MAX_RETURNED', 10);
define('QB_PRIORITY_ITEM', 3);
// Map QuickBooks actions to handler functions
$map = array(
    QUICKBOOKS_IMPORT_ITEM => array( '_quickbooks_item_import_request', '_quickbooks_item_import_response' ),
    QUICKBOOKS_ADD_INVENTORYADJUSTMENT => array( '_quickbooks_inventoryadjustment_add_request', '_quickbooks_inventoryadjustment_add_response' ),
);
// Trigger actions when errors are returned by QuickBooks
$errmap = array(
    3070 => '_quickbooks_error_stringtoolong',              // Whenever a string is too long to fit in a field, call this function: _quickbooks_error_stringtolong()
    // 'CustomerAdd' => '_quickbooks_error_customeradd',    // Whenever an error occurs while trying to perform an 'AddCustomer' action, call this function: _quickbooks_error_customeradd()
    1 => '_quickbooks_error_e500_notfound',
    '*' => '_quickbooks_error_catchall',                // Using a key value of '*' will catch any errors which were not caught by another error handler
    // ... more error handlers here ...
);
// An array of callback hooks
$hooks = array(
    QuickBooks_WebConnector_Handlers::HOOK_LOGINSUCCESS => '_quickbooks_hook_loginsuccess',     // call this whenever a successful login occurs
);
// Logging level
//$log_level = QUICKBOOKS_LOG_NORMAL;               
$log_level = QUICKBOOKS_LOG_DEVELOP;        // Use this level until you're sure everything works!!!
$soapserver = QUICKBOOKS_SOAPSERVER_BUILTIN;
$soap_options = array(      // See http://www.php.net/soap
);
$handler_options = array(
    'deny_concurrent_logins' => false, 
    'deny_reallyfast_logins' => false, 
);      // See the comments in the QuickBooks/Server/Handlers.php file
$driver_options = array(        // See the comments in the QuickBooks/Driver/<YOUR DRIVER HERE>.php file ( i.e. 'Mysql.php', etc. )
    //'max_log_history' => 1024,    // Limit the number of quickbooks_log entries to 1024
    //'max_queue_history' => 64,    // Limit the number of *successfully processed* quickbooks_queue entries to 64
);
$callback_options = array(
);
$dsn = 'mysqli://:@localhost/'; // User/pass removed
/**
 * Constant for the connection string (because we'll use it in other places in the script)
 */
define('QB_QUICKBOOKS_DSN', $dsn);
$qb = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'removed', 'removed', 'removed');
if (!QuickBooks_Utilities::initialized($dsn))
{
    // Create the tables
    $file = dirname(__FILE__) . '/import.sql';
    if (file_exists($file))
    {
        $contents = file_get_contents($file);   
        foreach (explode(';', $contents) as $sql)
        {
            if (!trim($sql))
            {
                continue;
            }
            mysqli_query($qb, $sql) or die(trigger_error(mysqli_error($qb)));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        die('Could not locate "./import.sql" to create the SQL schema!');
    }
    // Initialize creates the neccessary database schema for queueing up requests and logging
    QuickBooks_Utilities::initialize($dsn);
    // This creates a username and password which is used by the Web Connector to authenticate
    QuickBooks_Utilities::createUser($dsn, $user, $pass);
}
// Initialize the queue
QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue_Singleton::initialize($dsn);
// Create a new server and tell it to handle the requests
$Server = new QuickBooks_WebConnector_Server($dsn, $map, $errmap, $hooks, $log_level, $soapserver, QUICKBOOKS_WSDL, $soap_options, $handler_options, $driver_options, $callback_options);
$response = $Server->handle(true, true);
function _quickbooks_hook_loginsuccess($requestID, $user, $hook, &$err, $hook_data, $callback_config)
{
    // Fetch the queue instance
    $Queue = QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue_Singleton::getInstance();
    $date = '1983-01-02 12:01:01';
    // Set up the item imports
    if (!_quickbooks_get_last_run($user, QUICKBOOKS_IMPORT_ITEM))
    {
        _quickbooks_set_last_run($user, QUICKBOOKS_IMPORT_ITEM, $date);
    }
    // Make sure the requests get queued up
    $Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_IMPORT_ITEM, 1, QB_PRIORITY_ITEM);
}
/**
 * Get the last date/time the QuickBooks sync ran
 * 
 * @param string $user      The web connector username 
 * @return string           A date/time in this format: "yyyy-mm-dd hh:ii:ss"
 */
function _quickbooks_get_last_run($user, $action)
{
    $type = null;
    $opts = null;
    return QuickBooks_Utilities::configRead(QB_QUICKBOOKS_DSN, $user, md5(__FILE__), QB_QUICKBOOKS_CONFIG_LAST . '-' . $action, $type, $opts);
}
/**
 * Set the last date/time the QuickBooks sync ran to NOW
 * 
 * @param string $user
 * @return boolean
 */
function _quickbooks_set_last_run($user, $action, $force = null)
{
    $value = date('Y-m-d') . 'T' . date('H:i:s');
    if ($force)
    {
        $value = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($force)) . 'T' . date('H:i:s', strtotime($force));
    }
    return QuickBooks_Utilities::configWrite(QB_QUICKBOOKS_DSN, $user, md5(__FILE__), QB_QUICKBOOKS_CONFIG_LAST . '-' . $action, $value);
}

function _quickbooks_get_current_run($user, $action)
{
    $type = null;
    $opts = null;
    return QuickBooks_Utilities::configRead(QB_QUICKBOOKS_DSN, $user, md5(__FILE__), QB_QUICKBOOKS_CONFIG_CURR . '-' . $action, $type, $opts);  
}

function _quickbooks_set_current_run($user, $action, $force = null)
{
    $value = date('Y-m-d') . 'T' . date('H:i:s');
    if ($force)
    {
        $value = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($force)) . 'T' . date('H:i:s', strtotime($force));
    }
    return QuickBooks_Utilities::configWrite(QB_QUICKBOOKS_DSN, $user, md5(__FILE__), QB_QUICKBOOKS_CONFIG_CURR . '-' . $action, $value);   
}

/**
 * Build a request to import items already in QuickBooks into our application
 */
function _quickbooks_item_import_request($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale)
{
    // Iterator support (break the result set into small chunks)
    $attr_iteratorID = '';
    $attr_iterator = ' iterator="Start" ';
    if (empty($extra['iteratorID']))
    {
        // This is the first request in a new batch
        $last = _quickbooks_get_last_run($user, $action);
        _quickbooks_set_last_run($user, $action);           // Update the last run time to NOW()
        // Set the current run to $last
        _quickbooks_set_current_run($user, $action, $last);
    }
    else
    {
        // This is a continuation of a batch
        $attr_iteratorID = ' iteratorID="' . $extra['iteratorID'] . '" ';
        $attr_iterator = ' iterator="Continue" ';
        $last = _quickbooks_get_current_run($user, $action);
    }
    // Build the request
    $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <?qbxml version="' . $version . '"?>
        <QBXML>
            <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                <ItemQueryRq ' . $attr_iterator . ' ' . $attr_iteratorID . ' requestID="' . $requestID . '">
                    <MaxReturned>' . QB_QUICKBOOKS_MAX_RETURNED . '</MaxReturned>
                    <FromModifiedDate>' . $last . '</FromModifiedDate>
                    <OwnerID>0</OwnerID>
                </ItemQueryRq>  
            </QBXMLMsgsRq>
        </QBXML>';
    return $xml;
}
/** 
 * Handle a response from QuickBooks 
 */
function _quickbooks_item_import_response($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $xml, $idents)
{
    $Driver = QuickBooks_Driver_Singleton::getInstance();
    if (!empty($idents['iteratorRemainingCount']))
    {
        // Queue up another request
        $Queue = QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue_Singleton::getInstance();
        $Queue->enqueue(QUICKBOOKS_IMPORT_ITEM, null, QB_PRIORITY_ITEM, array( 'iteratorID' => $idents['iteratorID'] ));
    }
    // Import all of the records
    $errnum = 0;
    $errmsg = '';
    $Parser = new QuickBooks_XML_Parser($xml);
    if ($Doc = $Parser->parse($errnum, $errmsg))
    {
        $Root = $Doc->getRoot();
        $List = $Root->getChildAt('QBXML/QBXMLMsgsRs/ItemQueryRs');
        foreach ($List->children() as $Item)
        {
            $type = substr(substr($Item->name(), 0, -3), 4);
            $ret = $Item->name();
            $arr = array(
                'ListID' => $Item->getChildDataAt($ret . ' ListID'),
                'TimeCreated' => $Item->getChildDataAt($ret . ' TimeCreated'),
                'TimeModified' => $Item->getChildDataAt($ret . ' TimeModified'),
                'Name' => $Item->getChildDataAt($ret . ' Name'),
                'FullName' => $Item->getChildDataAt($ret . ' FullName'),
                'Type' => $type, 
                'Parent_ListID' => $Item->getChildDataAt($ret . ' ParentRef ListID'),
                'Parent_FullName' => $Item->getChildDataAt($ret . ' ParentRef FullName'),
                'ManufacturerPartNumber' => $Item->getChildDataAt($ret . ' ManufacturerPartNumber'), 
                'SalesTaxCode_ListID' => $Item->getChildDataAt($ret . ' SalesTaxCodeRef ListID'), 
                'SalesTaxCode_FullName' => $Item->getChildDataAt($ret . ' SalesTaxCodeRef FullName'), 
                'BuildPoint' => $Item->getChildDataAt($ret . ' BuildPoint'), 
                'ReorderPoint' => $Item->getChildDataAt($ret . ' ReorderPoint'), 
                'QuantityOnHand' => $Item->getChildDataAt($ret . ' QuantityOnHand'), 
                'AverageCost' => $Item->getChildDataAt($ret . ' AverageCost'), 
                'QuantityOnOrder' => $Item->getChildDataAt($ret . ' QuantityOnOrder'), 
                'QuantityOnSalesOrder' => $Item->getChildDataAt($ret . ' QuantityOnSalesOrder'),  
                'TaxRate' => $Item->getChildDataAt($ret . ' TaxRate'),  
                );
            $look_for = array(
                'SalesPrice' => array( 'SalesOrPurchase Price', 'SalesAndPurchase SalesPrice', 'SalesPrice' ),
                'SalesDesc' => array( 'SalesOrPurchase Desc', 'SalesAndPurchase SalesDesc', 'SalesDesc' ),
                'PurchaseCost' => array( 'SalesOrPurchase Price', 'SalesAndPurchase PurchaseCost', 'PurchaseCost' ),
                'PurchaseDesc' => array( 'SalesOrPurchase Desc', 'SalesAndPurchase PurchaseDesc', 'PurchaseDesc' ),
                'PrefVendor_ListID' => array( 'SalesAndPurchase PrefVendorRef ListID', 'PrefVendorRef ListID' ), 
                'PrefVendor_FullName' => array( 'SalesAndPurchase PrefVendorRef FullName', 'PrefVendorRef FullName' ),
                ); 
            foreach ($look_for as $field => $look_here)
            {
                if (!empty($arr[$field]))
                {
                    break;
                }
                foreach ($look_here as $look)
                {
                    $arr[$field] = $Item->getChildDataAt($ret . ' ' . $look);
                }
            }
            QuickBooks_Utilities::log(QB_QUICKBOOKS_DSN, 'Importing ' . $type . ' Item ' . $arr['FullName'] . ': ' . print_r($arr, true));
            foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
            {
                $arr[$key] = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $value);
            }

            //print_r(array_keys($arr));
            //trigger_error(print_r(array_keys($arr), true));
            // Store the customers in MySQL
            $Driver->query("
                REPLACE INTO
                    qb_item
                (
                    " . implode(", ", array_keys($arr)) . "
                ) VALUES (
                    '" . implode("', '", array_values($arr)) . "'
                )");
        }
    }
    return true;
}
/**
 * Generate a qbXML response to add a particular inventory adjustment to QuickBooks
 * 
 * @return string                           A valid qbXML request
 */
function _quickbooks_inventoryadjustment_add_request($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale, $callback_config)
{
    $Driver = QuickBooks_Driver_Singleton::getInstance();
    $errnum = null;
    $errmsg = null;
    $data = $Driver->fetch($Driver->query("SELECT * FROM qb_inventoryadjustment WHERE qbsql_id = %d", $errnum, $errmsg, 0, 1, array( $ID )));
    $res_lines = $Driver->query("SELECT * FROM qb_inventoryadjustment_inventoryadjustmentline WHERE InventoryAdjustment_TxnID = '%s' ORDER BY SortOrder ASC", $errnum, $errmsg, null, null, array( $data['TxnID'] ));
    /*foreach ($data as $key => $value)
    {
        $data[$key] = QuickBooks_Cast::cast(QUICKBOOKS_OBJECT_CUSTOMER, str_replace('_', ' ', $key), $value);
    }*/
    $str_action = 'InventoryAdjustmentAdd';
    $TxnID = '';
    $EditSequence = '';
    if ($action == 'InventoryAdjustmentMod')
    {
        $str_action = 'InventoryAdjustmentMod';
        $TxnID = '<TxnID>' . $data['TxnID'] . '</TxnID>';
        $EditSequence = '<EditSequence>' . $data['EditSequence'] . '</EditSequence>';
    }
    $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <?qbxml version="' . $version . '"?>
        <QBXML>
            <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                <' . $str_action . 'Rq requestID="' . $requestID . '">
                    <' . $str_action . '>
                        ' . $TxnID . '
                        ' . $EditSequence . '

                        <AccountRef>
                            <FullName>' . $data['Account_FullName'] . '</FullName>
                        </AccountRef>

                        <TxnDate>' . $data['TxnDate'] . '</TxnDate>
                        <!--<RefNumber>' . $data['RefNumber'] . '</RefNumber>-->

                        <Memo>' . $data['Memo'] . '</Memo>
                        ';

    while ($line = $Driver->fetch($res_lines))
    {
        $xml .= '
                        <InventoryAdjustmentLineAdd>
                            <ItemRef>';

        if ($line['Item_ListID'])
        {
            $xml .= '
                                <ListID>' . $line['Item_ListID'] . '</ListID>';
        }
        else
        {
            $xml .= '
                                <FullName>' . $line['Item_FullName'] . '</FullName>';
        }

        $xml .= '
                            </ItemRef>

                            <QuantityAdjustment>';

        if ($line['QuantityDifference'])
        {
            $xml .= '
                                <QuantityDifference>' . $line['QuantityDifference'] . '</QuantityDifference>';
        }
        else
        {
            $xml .= '
                                <NewQuantity>' . $line['NewQuantity'] . '</NewQuantity>';
        }

        $xml .= '
                            </QuantityAdjustment>
                        </InventoryAdjustmentLineAdd>
                ';
    }

    $xml .= '

                    </' . $str_action . '>
                </' . $str_action . 'Rq>
            </QBXMLMsgsRq>
        </QBXML>';

    return $xml;
}

/**
 * Receive a response from QuickBooks 
 */
function _quickbooks_inventoryadjustment_add_response($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $xml, $idents, $callback_config)
{   
    $Driver = QuickBooks_Driver_Singleton::getInstance();

    $datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $errnum = null;
    $errmsg = null;
    $data = $Driver->fetch($Driver->query("SELECT * FROM qb_inventoryadjustment WHERE qbsql_id = %d", $errnum, $errmsg, 0, 1, array( $ID )));

    if ($data)
    {
        // Get the existing lines 
        $res_lines = $Driver->query("SELECT * FROM qb_inventoryadjustment_inventoryadjustmentline WHERE InventoryAdjustment_TxnID = '%s' ORDER BY qbsql_id ASC ", $errnum, $errmsg, null, null, array( $data['TxnID'] ));

        // Update ListID/EditSequence
        $errnum = null;
        $errmsg = null;
        $Driver->query("
            UPDATE 
                qb_inventoryadjustment
            SET 
                TxnID = '%s', 
                EditSequence = '%s', 
                TimeCreated = '%s', 
                TimeModified = '%s', 
                RefNumber = '%s', 
                qbsql_discov_datetime = '%s', 
                qbsql_resync_datetime = '%s', 
                qbsql_modify_timestamp = '%s'
            WHERE 
                qbsql_id = %d ", $errnum, $errmsg, 0, 1, 
            array( 
                $idents['TxnID'], 
                $idents['EditSequence'], 
                date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 
                date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 
                $idents['RefNumber'],
                $datetime, 
                $datetime, 
                $datetime,
                $ID ));

        // Parse the XML we got back 
        // Import all of the records
        $errnum = 0;
        $errmsg = '';
        $Parser = new QuickBooks_XML_Parser($xml);
        if ($Doc = $Parser->parse($errnum, $errmsg))
        {
            $Root = $Doc->getRoot();
            $List = $Root->getChildAt('QBXML/QBXMLMsgsRs/InventoryAdjustmentAddRs');

            $TxnLineIDs = array();

            foreach ($List->children() as $InventoryAdjustment)
            {
                // Process the line items
                foreach ($InventoryAdjustment->children() as $Child)
                {
                    if ($Child->name() == 'InventoryAdjustmentLineRet')
                    {
                        // Store the TxnLineID
                        $TxnLineIDs[] = $Child->getChildDataAt('InventoryAdjustmentLineRet TxnLineID');
                    }
                }
            }

            reset($TxnLineIDs);
            while ($line = $Driver->fetch($res_lines))
            {
                $TxnLineID = current($TxnLineIDs);
                next($TxnLineIDs);

                // Update each line item with the TxnID and the TxnLineID 
                $Driver->query("
                    UPDATE 
                        qb_inventoryadjustment_inventoryadjustmentline
                    SET 
                        InventoryAdjustment_TxnID = '%s', 
                        TxnLineID = '%s', 
                        qbsql_discov_datetime = '%s', 
                        qbsql_resync_datetime = '%s', 
                        qbsql_modify_timestamp = '%s'
                    WHERE 
                        qbsql_id = %d ", $errnum, $errmsg, null, null,  
                    array( 
                        $idents['TxnID'], 
                        $TxnLineID, 
                        $datetime, 
                        $datetime, 
                        $datetime,
                        $line['qbsql_id'] ));
            }
        }

    }
}

/**
 * Catch and handle a "that string is too long for that field" error (err no. 3070) from QuickBooks
 * 
 * @param string $requestID         
 * @param string $action
 * @param mixed $ID
 * @param mixed $extra
 * @param string $err
 * @param string $xml
 * @param mixed $errnum
 * @param string $errmsg
 * @return void
 */
function _quickbooks_error_stringtoolong($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $xml, $errnum, $errmsg)
{
    mail(QB_QUICKBOOKS_MAILTO, 
        'QuickBooks error occured!', 
        'QuickBooks thinks that ' . $action . ': ' . $ID . ' has a value which will not fit in a QuickBooks field...');
}

/**
 * Handle a 500 not found error from QuickBooks
 * 
 * Instead of returning empty result sets for queries that don't find any 
 * records, QuickBooks returns an error message. This handles those error 
 * messages, and acts on them by adding the missing item to QuickBooks. 
 */
function _quickbooks_error_e500_notfound($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $xml, $errnum, $errmsg)
{
    //$Queue = QuickBooks_WebConnector_Queue_Singleton::getInstance();

    if ($action == QUICKBOOKS_IMPORT_ITEM) {
        return true;
    } elseif ($action == QUICKBOOKS_ADD_INVENTORYADJUSTMENT) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}


/**
 * Catch any errors that occur
 * 
 * @param string $requestID         
 * @param string $action
 * @param mixed $ID
 * @param mixed $extra
 * @param string $err
 * @param string $xml
 * @param mixed $errnum
 * @param string $errmsg
 * @return void
 */
function _quickbooks_error_catchall($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $xml, $errnum, $errmsg)
{
    $message = '';
    $message .= 'Request ID: ' . $requestID . "\r\n";
    $message .= 'User: ' . $user . "\r\n";
    $message .= 'Action: ' . $action . "\r\n";
    $message .= 'ID: ' . $ID . "\r\n";
    $message .= 'Extra: ' . print_r($extra, true) . "\r\n";
    $message .= 'Error: ' . $err . "\r\n";
    $message .= 'Error number: ' . $errnum . "\r\n";
    $message .= 'Error message: ' . $errmsg . "\r\n";

    mail(QB_QUICKBOOKS_MAILTO, 
        'QuickBooks error occured!', 
        $message);
}
```

**PHP error_log**

```
[27-Dec-2016 17:46:12 America/Chicago] PHP Deprecated:  Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead. in Unknown on line 0
[27-Dec-2016 15:46:12 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Warning:  require_once(/home2/spray/public_html/qb/QuickBooks/Driver/.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home2/spray/public_html/qb/QuickBooks/Loader.php on line 56
[27-Dec-2016 15:46:12 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home2/spray/public_html/qb/QuickBooks/Driver/.php' (include_path='.:/opt/php56/lib/php:/home2/spray/public_html/qb') in /home2/spray/public_html/qb/QuickBooks/Loader.php on line 56
```

Comment: @Keith Palmer Jr. Updated OP with error_log, seems it's having trouble loading the driver module. Probably a pathing issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I added the PHP tag, which seems quite essential to your question. It would be good if you could reduce the PHP code block to the essence related to the problem, since people will in general not be likely to go through the 500+ lines you posted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anytime you see something like this:

```
20161227.23:47:12 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.do_receiveResponseXML() : QBWC1042: ReceiveResponseXML failed
Error message: Response is not well-formed XML.
```

There's about a 99% chance that you have an error in your PHP or SQL.

Based on these errors you're seeing in the logs:

```
[27-Dec-2016 15:46:12 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Warning:  require_once(/home2/spray/public_html/qb/QuickBooks/Driver/.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home2/spray/public_html/qb/QuickBooks/Loader.php on line 56
[27-Dec-2016 15:46:12 America/Los_Angeles] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/home2/spray/public_html/qb/QuickBooks/Driver/.php' (include_path='.:/opt/php56/lib/php:/home2/spray/public_html/qb') in /home2/spray/public_html/qb/QuickBooks/Loader.php on line 56
```

You probably didn't initialize the database singleton you're using. This gets the singleton instance:

```
$Driver = QuickBooks_Driver_Singleton::getInstance();
```

But you have to initialize it first (before you create your `QuickBooks_WebConnector_Server` class):

```
QuickBooks_Driver_Singleton::initialize('mysqli://user:pass@host/db');
```

Or just use the `mysqli_*` functions like the example shows.

I see another potential problem, which is that this line:

```
$arr[$key] = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $value);
```

Uses an undefined variable named `$con`. Make sure you go through your code and ensure your code is correct and variables are defined.

Comment: From what I seen earlier at work just mainly quite a few auto populating POST variable errors. I'll look at it in detail tomorrow morning.

Comment: Initializing the driver was exactly what I needed, thanks! $con was when I was using mysqli_query(), etc. to accomplish what I am now trying to do using the driver module. However, $Driver->query() seemingly needs to be passed references for $errnum & $err, should I just supply empty variables?

Comment: Yes, empty is fine. They are pass-by-reference and pass error messages back to you.